# Does False and True equal False?

Tags: python

I don't know if this is a trick question but my homework is asking me if

> False and True will equal False

Putting in

```
False and True
```

in juypter returns False but I want to make sure this isn't a trick question

Comment: This is standard logic, not specific to Python. The output of an `and` operation is only true if both inputs are true.

Comment: You should learn the basics of formal logic. Take a look at this: https://www.fecundity.com/codex/forallx.pdf

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_conjunction#Truth_table

Comment: `false = True; print(false and True)`

Comment: This is a great example of where you should just try it out. And it sounds like you _have_. Why don't you trust what you're seeing?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is False. Please looking to logical operators

Comment: Or, indeed, logical operators anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, `and` means that both conditions are true. One of them is hardcoded to `False`, so no, it can't be true.

Think about it this way: if I said "all dogs are cats," that's clearly a false statement. If I said "all horses are mammals," that's clearly a true statement. If I said "all dogs are cats AND all horses are mammals," that's *still* a false statement (even though the second clause is true) because I'm claiming that a clearly false statement is true.